# vbs text concatenation not working with wscript.arguments

Tags: vbscript

I made a js script to convert text to speech and running a command line with vbs to keep the console window hidden. I am calling via a command so Im trying to use the parameters passed in to it.

I tried using the '+' operator like in most other languages but it didn't work, then I tried the '&' operator but to no success :(.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c node audio.js" + WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

Comment: string concatenation in vbscript is definitely `&`. If you are seeing something that you don't expect then it is probably due to other reasons than the concatenation not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot a space I feel so dumb

Answer (score 0):

This

```
C:\Users\eh
type 56861329.vbs
WScript.Echo "cmd /c node audio.js" + WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

C:\Users\eh
cscript 56861329.vbs MissingSpace
cmd /c node audio.jsMissingSpace
```

should show the real problem. As @Geert said, `&` is the VBScript operator for concatenation and should be used.